# “No options in dynamically provided” intent for widget

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget

The error message “No options were provided for this parameter” may occur when a Widget uses a custom type and dynamic options are selected, but the options are not correctly passed to the component at runtime.

Here is my intent code, I originally intended to retrieve data from CoreData, but even when I tried to assign values directly, I still couldn’t retrieve any data.

```swift
class IntentHandler: INExtension, CreateItemConfigurationIntentHandling {
  let context = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext

  func provideTagsOptionsCollection(for intent: CreateItemConfigurationIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<WidgetTag>?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let options = [
      WidgetTag(identifier: "option1", display: "Option 1"),
      WidgetTag(identifier: "option2", display: "Option 2"),
      WidgetTag(identifier: "option3", display: "Option 3")
    ]
    
    let collection = INObjectCollection(items: options)
    completion(collection, nil)
  }
}
```

The following is the configuration of the `.intentdefinition` file:
[image]

The following are the configurations of the .intentdefinition file and the target setting of the IntentHandler:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've stumbled on the same issue the other day.

I find the solutions in https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663879?login=true&page=1#761400022 very helpful.

In summary, to debug this issue, first add breakpoints to your intent handler class, run your intent handler scheme, and use the widget to trigger your breakpoints.

If your breakpoints do not trigger, it could be the following causes.

1. Your intent is not declared in the info.plist of the intent handler target.
2. Your intent handler's iOS target version is too high to run on your testing device.

Once the above issue is resolved or if the breakpoints trigger successfully, you can then use the breakpoints to further debug why the returned data is empty.
It could be following reasons.

1. Data is not shared through AppGroup.
2. AppGroup not added both to the capabilities of the main app and the intent handler target.
3. Incorrect app group name.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you. My problem is intent's minimum iOS version.